# Why my color theme change when I change java 8 version (from 8u45 to 8u171)?

Tags: java, swing, java-8, jide

I have an application that I can launch with two differents versions of java:

- with 8u45, my application get shade of blue
  [image: application blue]
- with 8u171, my application get shade of white
  [image: application white]

I checked the lookandfile init in the application but it doesn't seem to affect this behaviour.

**I use Swing and Jide 3.6.0 librairy**

Has someone an idea why this behavior is happening when I upgrade java version from 8u45 to 8u171 ?

Thanks for your help :)

**Edit :**

The application is running on Windows.

I use com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel, given by UIManager.getLookAndFeel()

Comment: What is the Look and Feel that you are using for Swing? Could it be that you are running this app on Windows?

Comment: It seems that I use com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel, given by UIManager.getLookAndFeel(). And yes the application running on Windows. Good point :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is linked to the system property *os.name*. Since windows 8.1, the GetVersionEx function has been deprecated whereas old version of java 8 such as 8u45 are based on this function to feed this system property.

For more information : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/targeting-your-application-at-windows-8-1

So that when you launch a jvm with this version of java, it will consider windows 8.1 
 os name and apply its skin.
A quick test can support this statement by displaying System.getProperty("os.name") with the old jdk 8u45 :
[image: System.getProperty("os.name")]

I suppose later version of java 8 fixed this issue and retrieve the good os name. For example with jdk u171 :

[image: System.getProperty("os.name")]